# LWC child to parent communication

Tags: lightning-web-components

parent.html

```
<a href="" onclick= {handleclick}> click here</a>
<c-modal open = {openModal}>
```

Paren.js

```
@track openModal;

  handleclick(){

   this.openModal = true;
}
```

when I close the Modal in the "modal" component , how do I communicate it back to the parent component or how do I change back the value of reactive property to false after click operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use custom events. Example:
hmtl

```
<a href="" onclick= {handleclick}> click here</a>
<c-modal onclose={handleModalClosed} open = {openModal}>
```

js

```
@track openModal;

  handleclick(){

   this.openModal = true;
  }

  handleModalClose() {
   this.openModal = false;
  }
```

c-modal:

```
closeModal() {
  //do modal close stuff
  this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('close'));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Child-to-parent communication is always done with [events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch).

```
<c-modal open={openModal} onclose={notifyClose}></c-modal>
```

...

```
// in modal
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('close'));
```

...

```
// in parent
notifyClose() {
    this.openModal = false;
}
```